# Flutter and Firebase admin and normal user login

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

hello i am new to flutter and firebase and i have a field in the user document that is called admin and it's a boolean , i want to check this boolean in the sign in functionality .
what i came up so far is this :

```
onPressed: () async {
  if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
    if (!await user.signIn(_email.text, _password.text)) {
      toast("Signin Faild");
    } else {
      if(await _firestore.collection('users').doc(_auth.currentUser.uid).get().)
        changeScreenReplacement(context, HomePage());
      toast("Signedin successfully");
    }
  }
},
```

i don't know what to do in this part :
`if(await _firestore.collection('users').doc(_auth.currentUser.uid).get().)`

i want here to check the field if it's equal to true or false how can i do this ?

Comment: Could you please print(await _firestore.collection('users').doc(_auth.currentUser.uid).get()) before the if statement and see what it returns?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check if the user return true or false, you can do as following:

```
onPressed: () async {
  if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
    if (!await user.signIn(_email.text, _password.text)) {
      toast("Signin Faild");
    } else {
      FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
      DocumentReference document = await _firestore.collection('users').doc(user.uid).get()
      if(document.data['admin'] == true)
        changeScreenReplacement(context, HomePage());
      toast("Signedin successfully");
    }
  }
},
```

You can also check the [Flutter Documentation](https://flutter-examples.com/if-else-conditional-statement-in-flutter-dart/)